# How to set different column value for checkbox in Magento Grid

Tags: magento

We are creating a custom module in magento and want to displaying a product list in admin panel using magento grid.

As this grid showing a checkbox column to perform mass actions and this checkbox column taking product id as checkbox value.

But, we want to set different column value for checkbox column like product attribute set id. So, there is any way to change the value of checkbox set value as the attribute set id instead of product id on column value.

Please give me the solution to how to do that so that we can change the value of checkbox column.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes appears from the function

> _prepareMassaction()

in your grid. Have a look at this function

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
```

Below code sets the id.

```
   $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
```

The entity id is coming from the collection you get from the function

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

If you can modify this collection to get your attribute set id here. than you can use that id in the

```
   $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
```

To achieve what you need.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, Your solution is appreciated and its working fine. But we want a little change in the checkbox value. Now we want to customize the value of checkbox like setting the value seperated by underscore(_) i.e 289_234 instead of a single value like 289. Is there any method to customize the checkbox value?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to seperate the value by underscore(_) because magento passes those values in an array. $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids'); This line does the work but if you want to pass it seperating by underscore than you need to get the ids of the checked values and than append it to a string with _ and than pass it to controller. But if this is not necessary than i suggest you use magento default functionality of passing it into array. Or either you can further append it in controller too. Either way you like.

Comment: setMassactionIdField does not work if it is not from the primary collection (say another column) from a join that was made